# how to show that $f(x) = x^{1/3}$ on [-1,1] is the indefinite integral of $g$ over $[-1,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, lebesgue-integral

How to show that $f(x) = x^{1/3}$ on [-1,1] is the indefinite integral of $g$ over $[-1,1]$?

I want to show that $f$ is an indefinite integral. I know that $f'(x)=\frac{1}{3}x^{-2/3}$and it is integrable so I can take it as $g.$ Also, I know that the definition of $f$ being indefinite integral of $g$ over $[a,b]$ provided $g$ is Lebesgue integrable over $[a,b]$ is that: $$f(x) = f(a) + \int_{a}^{x} g$$ for all $x \in [a,b].$

But how can I calculate  $\int_{a}^{x} g,$ is it the ordinary integration which is equal to $\frac{1}{3}x^{-2/3} - \frac{1}{3}a^{-2/3}$, if so how will this give me the LHS, could anyone explains this for me please?

Also what about the point $0$ in the interval $[-1,1]$?

**EDIT:**

in the interval $[-1,1]$, the LHS will give me 2 while the RHS will give me 0.

Comment: you will have to break up your problem to one over $[-1,0)$ and $(0,1]$ and then apply the logc you are describing

Comment: $\frac{1}{3}a^{-2/3}?$ how I will sustitute by $0$ instead of $a$ here @gt6989b

Comment: I am not sure the integral exists at zero. That argument will hold over $[-1,\epsilon)  \cup (\epsilon,1]$ with any $\epsilon > 0$

Comment: does it matter if I neglect one point from the interval?

Comment: Not sure if Riemann or Lebesgue integrable will make a difference here. Usually removing a finite amount of points does not affect the integration